# Flask user_id returns NoneType when a script is called?

Tags: python, flask, paramiko, flask-login

I have a small issue of not being able to call a username in my flask app- I need to be able to call a script from a page in my app, and use the current logged in username to run portions of the script. However, when the script is fired up, user_id has NoneType and cannot locate the logged in user!

Here is some code:

app/view/views.py

```
@app.route('/compute', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def compute():
    form = RadioForm(request.form)
    hlaargs = form.hlaradio.data
    print hlaargs
    form.validate_on_submit()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if hlaargs == '1':
            id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            background_scripts[id] = False
            threading.Thread(target=lambda: run_script1(id)).start()
            return render_template('pages/processing.html', id=id)
```

another part of app/view/views.py

```
def run_script1(id):
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "*/sshattempt1.py"])
    background_scripts[id] = True
```

app/machine/sshattempt1.py

```
today = datetime.date.today()
current = current_user.get_id()
usrtdy = current + '/' + str(today)
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("*.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()

c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "connecting"
....
```

any ideas on what I am missing? I just need the user to stay consistent throughout the entire app! thanks!

Comment: I can't see what any of that code has to do with your problem description. Where are you using `user_id`?

Comment: i guess current_user.get_id is what i'm speaking of, since it would and does normally return the user_id in other places in my app. I apologize if you misunderstood

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I believe you need to access current_user within the application context. Pass your script the user_id. If you need the User object, query it from within your other process.

Comment: But... that script is not executed inside your app. You've called out to a separate process (from inside a thread, for reasons I don't understand, but never mind). Your subprocess can't have any idea who's logged in to your Flask app.

Comment: I'm pretty new at this, so don't crucify me- but i use the thread to link to a jquery to tell me when the process is done running, and redirect me accordingly. How can I pass user credentials through the subprocess? And am I using threading correctly?

Comment: You're not using threading correctly. If you want to pass data structures around to your threads and processes you need a thread safe data structure. These exist for Python but essentially it is easier to pass a value - in this case it would be your user_id - and then build your data structure from there. That way you have no concurrency issues.